# Unclassifiable statement when calling function exp(x)

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I found this error! How can I resolve it?

Compiling the source code....

```
$gfortran -std=f95 main.f95 -o demo 2>&1
main.f95:14:

f(x)=exp(x)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Comment: Can you give us a minimally-reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

If

```
f(x)=exp(x)
```

is a valid Fortran expression then it might be a *statement function*.  This is a now-obsolescent feature that is best avoided.  I'm not very familiar with gfortran, it seems possible that the compilation option `std=f95` is saving you from yourself by not letting you use the feature.

It's possible that it assigns the value of `exp(x)` to the `x`-th element of an array called `f` but that suggests that `x` is an integer.

It's also possible that that is not the cause of the compilation error.  It's possible that the statement function is in the wrong place within the source unit.  Fortran is very particular about the ordering of statements in source unit.  Statement functions must appear before any executable statements in a source unit.